# Magento2: How to use flat table instead of EAV?

Tags: magento2, php, database

I have a Magento 2 project, in which the customer will have only a very few attributes. So instead of EAV a want to use Flat tables. i.e I want all the attributes to be columns.

Customer Address will remain out of this and will work as is (default implementation).

Has anyone done anything like this in magento 1 or 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Magento has a predefined tables' structure and in order to modify it, you would need to make many big modifications in the core functionality flow.

By default, it uses EAV database structure to save the data of major entities i.e. Categories, Products, Customers, and Orders.

**For the backend, Magento uses EAV tables only to save or show the data.**

**For the frontend, you can enable the flat catalog from the Catalog settings.**

If you want the flat tables only for backend also, then you are going to reinvent the wheel in Magento.

This step may affect the **performance** of the store.

It would be better to go with some other platform like Opencart in that case.